# Writing to a stream on a PostgreSQL trigger using Python

Tags: python, postgresql, triggers, node.js

I would like to write a trigger for a PostgreSQL database which, on insertions, would notify a node.js server which would send some data to connected clients.

Currently, my thought is to write a Python row insert trigger for the database which would write data to some file which would then be read by the node.js server.

However, this would be slow, as disk access would be involved. What would be a better way to connect these two applications?

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at Listen Notify functionality?
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/interactive/sql-notify.html

Also you will want to test out different options against your needs, instead of assuming one is not fast enough for what you need.  Maybe your python approach will work just fine.

Comment: +1. Not sure if node.js supports asynchronous LISTEN/NOTIFY, but if it does, this is certainly the best mechanism for such uses.

Comment: If not you could continuously pole in a loop if that's possible under your condition.

Comment: As simple as it may sound, polling is actually *quite hard* to implement in a race-condition-free manner. Imagine two inserts, a transaction that inserted a row earlier (thus with a lower ID and time), but committed later than the other insert. Though you could use advisory locks or similar to serialize inserts, it may kill performance.

Comment: Thanks, this makes a lot of sense and seems like a better way of going about this. I'll have to check if Node.js supports listen/notify, and if not, perhaps using a different server.